# ReactJs imported function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, undefined

I am trying to figure out why one of the function call is returning "undefined" while I expect to receive the context value of my app. I am quite new to ReactJS and I am trying to make one of the project I have works.

I have a basic page containing a login props

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { Login } from "./Login";
import { useAppContext } from "context/AppContext";
import { loginApi } from "services/api";
import { useApi } from "services/api/api.hook";

const EnhancedLogin = (props) => {
  const { dispatch } = useAppContext();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("RD@test.com");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("AnotherTest");
  const [, , setParamsUser] = useApi({});
  const history = useHistory();

  const login = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const res = await loginApi({ password, email });
[...]
```

One of the const of this props is using "useApi({})"

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import { useAppContext } from "context/AppContext";

export const useApi = ({ params: passedParams, defaultValue }) => {  
  const { dispatch } = useAppContext();
  const [params, setParams] = useState(passedParams || false);
  const [data, setData] = useState(defaultValue);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    setError(null);
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      dispatch({
        type: "ADD_APICALL",
        payload: `${params.method}-${params.namespace}`,
      });
```

Unfortunately, most of the time "dispatch" is considered as undefined (as shown in the screenshot) while normally, it should returns the current context value, as given by the nearest context provider for the given context.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';

const defaultValues = { context: 'green' };

const AppContext = React.createContext(defaultValues);

export const useAppContext = () => useContext(AppContext);

export default AppContext;
```

[Debug Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox3x7.png)
[Debug Output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9q36.png)

Could you please enlighten me  ?

- Annex

```
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.7.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "npm": "^6.14.11",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "^0.63.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.32.7",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
```

Comment: Your `AppContext` initial value is `{ context: 'green' }`... where do you get a `dispatch` function from? Where do you provide your context value, i.e. `<AppContext.Provider value={{ ..... }} />{children}</AppContext.Provider>`?

Comment: I guess the creator of this code used this initial value without any purpose, it's not used afterwards
Dispatch is the local name of the constant which is initiated at the beginning of useAPI with the value of useAppContext() which itself use useContext

I didn't find any reference to usage/assigment/code like you mentioned.